# How to use xml serialized string in php?

Tags: php, xml

This is my code:

```
$php_var = json_decode($json, 1);

$serializer=new XML_Serializer();
if($serializer->serialize($php_var))
$xml_string=htmlspecialchars("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>".$serializer->getSerializedData());
echo $xml_string; 
$xml_obj = new DOMDocument;
@$xml_obj->loadXML($xml_string);

$urls=$xml_obj->getElementsByTagName('visibleUrl');
foreach($urls as $u)
      {
        echo $u->textContent."<br/>";
      }
```

Comment: Stack overflow is about asking and answering questions, not posting random snippets of code. How often I see these kinds of posts is maddeningly frustrating.

Comment: Yes, this looks pretty useless. You'll need to explain what you are trying to accomplish. Why don't you access the array data directly?

Comment: just to ensure i didnot over-edit...roll-back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the XML part and use the parsed JSON structure directly.

```
 print_r($php_var);
```

Will show you the content. If you're looking for some "visibleUrl" string, then traverse the array recursively until you find it.

You might try [Dynamic Array traversal in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930833/dynamic-array-traversal-in-php)