# Multidimensional array having array and non array as elements , traversal in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How could I traverse a structure like below:

```
    $this->user[$userid] =  array(
                                 "initial" => array(
                                              "amount" =>$amount,
                                              "cards" =>$cards
                                              ),
                                 "userturn" => array(
                                               "userturn1" => array(
                                                              "action"=>$action,
                                                              "amount"=>$amount,
                                                              "date"=>$datetime 
                                                              ),
                                                "userturn2" => array(
                                                              "action"=>$action,
                                                              "amount"=>$amount,
                                                              "date"=>$datetime 
                                                              ),
                                                              .
                                                              .
                                                              .
                                                              .
                                                              n times
                                                     )                                                                

                         );
```

Comment: With a nested `for` loop or a recursive function.

Comment: First of all format it properly so we don't traverse our neck trying to read it!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930833/dynamic-array-traversal-in-php

Comment: **Recommendation:** you could include the code you currently have in your question, so that we can help you improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to get to turns..

```
foreach($this->user[$userid]['userturn'] as $k=>$turn){
    print_r($turn);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. what could i do if don't know userid ?

Comment: Then you need two cycles
`foreach($this->user as $userid=>$turns){
foreach($turns[$userid]['userturn'] as $k=>$turn){
print_r($turn);
}
}`

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. You made my day. Hats off to you

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple recursion:

```
function recurseLoop($arr){
    foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
         echo('key:' . $key);
         if(gettype($value) == 'array'){
             recurseLoop($value);
         }
         else{
            echo('value:' . $value);
         }

    }
}

recurseLoop($this->user[$userid]);
```